# Python Polars Expression For Cumulative Row Count by Day by Category

Tags: python, python-polars

Given a polars dataframe

```
import datetime
import polars as pl


df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": [
            datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 9),
            datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10),
            datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 12),
            datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2, 9),
            datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2, 10),
            datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 3, 12),
        ],
        "category": [1,1,2,1,2,1],
    }
)
```

I am seeking an expression `row_count_by_day` such that

```
expr = ...alias("row_count_by_day")
df = df.with_column(expr)
print(df)
```

yields

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────────────┐
│ time                ┆ category ┆ row_count_by_day │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      ┆ ---              │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64      ┆ i64              │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╪══════════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 09:00:00 ┆ 1        ┆ 1                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2023-01-01 10:00:00 ┆ 1        ┆ 2                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2023-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ 2        ┆ 1                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2023-01-02 09:00:00 ┆ 1        ┆ 1                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2023-01-02 10:00:00 ┆ 2        ┆ 1                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2023-01-03 12:00:00 ┆ 1        ┆ 1                │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┴──────────────────┘
```

That is, the cumulative row count for a particular category in a single day.

Ideally also I'd like to extend this to multiple categories. e.g. If category 1 has 5 rows with the same value in another column, they'd only be counted once.

I tried several combinations of window functions over category, but being a novice in polars, I didn't get close. My best guess was some sort of `rolling_sum` of a constant column with ones over the category with a window size of `1d`. I couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [`.dt.truncate`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.truncate.html#polars.Expr.dt.truncate) is the piece you're missing.

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.first().cumcount()
     .over(pl.col("time").dt.truncate("1d"), "category")
     .alias("count") + 1
)
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ time                ┆ category ┆ count │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64      ┆ u32   │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-01-01 09:00:00 ┆ 1        ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-01-01 10:00:00 ┆ 1        ┆ 2     │
│ 2023-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ 2        ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-01-02 09:00:00 ┆ 1        ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-01-02 10:00:00 ┆ 2        ┆ 1     │
│ 2023-01-03 12:00:00 ┆ 1        ┆ 1     │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
    df.with_columns(
    row_count_by_day=pl.repeat(1,pl.count())
    .cumsum()
    .over(
        pl.col('time')
        .dt.truncate("1d"),
        'category'))
```

The weird thing here is the `pl.repeat(1,pl.count())` which seems like it's the same thing as `pl.lit(1)` but it's not because of the way polars broadcasts the scalar 1. If you do two contexts like this:

```
df.with_columns(one=pl.lit(1)).with_columns(
    row_count_by_day=pl.col('one')
    .cumsum()
    .over(
        pl.col('time')
        .dt.truncate("1d"),
        'category')).drop('one')
```

then the first `with_columns` broadcasts the 1 to all rows so then the second context works when referring to the `one` column.